# Agrupar registros en consulta MySQL

Tags: mysql, mysqli

colegas, pido de su apoyo en relación al siguiente problema que tengo acerca de agrupar las consultas que obtengo.

Tengo 3 tablas en mi BD las cuales están relacionadas de la siguiente forma.

1. Usuarios
2. Clientes
3. Intereses

Usuarios a Clientes
Clientes a Intereses

En la tabla Clientes tengo un campo llamado Intereses los cuales se guardan los "ID" de la Tabla de Intereses, lo que busco con mi consulta es que me muestre mendiante un JOIN los intereses que tiene ese Cliente.

Mi consulta es la Siguiente:

```
SELECT
c.email,
c.rol,
DATE_FORMAT( c.actividad, '%d de %M del %Y a las %h:%i:%s %p' ) AS act,
b.nombres,
DATE_FORMAT( b.fecha_alta, '%d de %M del %Y' ) AS fecha,
i.`name` 
FROM
usuarios c
INNER JOIN clientes b ON c.id_cliente = b.id
LEFT JOIN cat_intereses i ON 0 != FIND_IN_SET( i.id, b.intereses ) ORDER BY
b.fecha_alta DESC
```

Tengo 2 registros de Prueba en mis tablas, sin embargo con esta consulta me muestra 3 registros.

| email | rol | act | nombres | fecha | name |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| lopez@hotmail.com | 1 | 26 de May del 2023 a las 12:37:16 AM | Javier Lopez | 26 de May del 2023 | Diseño |
| lopez@hotmail.com | 1 | 26 de May del 2023 a las 12:37:16 AM | Javier Lopez | 26 de May del 2023 | Desarrollo Personal |
| marquez@hotmail.com | 2 | 26 de May del 2023 a las 12:37:16 AM | Francisco Marquez | 25 de April del 2023 | Artes Plásticas y Dibujo |

Lo que busco es que los primeros 2 registros que pertenecen a mismo cliente se agrupen ya que el tiene 2 intereses registrados en su tabla Clientes: (Ejemplo)

| id | idUsuario | intereses |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1,4 |

No se si me explico, espero y puedan apoyarme.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes que agruparlos primeramente por nombre o algún identificador que tengas y después para que se muestren en la misma fila, tienes que ocupar una función llamada GROUP_CONCAT.

Te dejo el link por aquí abajo para que lo apliques para solucionar tu problema:

[GROUP_CONCAT](https://www.w3resource.com/mysql/aggregate-functions-and-grouping/aggregate-functions-and-grouping-group_concat.php)

Comment: Muchas Gracias por el apoyo, ya lo integre  @rodrigo